# How to solve Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR) in android app?

Tags: android, crash, android-workmanager

I am getting below error and app crashes while uploading a video as chunks in my app. I have a OneTime Work Manager created to handle the chunking and upload of video. Every time when it reaches 151th chunk, right after posting the request, this crash happens. I am using CoroutineWorker and i have DB update on each chunk response.

For testing purposes I have moved chunking to viewmodel and for each chunk, i create a work manager. In this case it doesnt crash, only in have scenario it does.

I am not doing anything related to NDK in my app. Tried many things seen in other people's similar problem solutions but nothing worked. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x6cc2ca78a0 in tid 10169 (DefaultDispatch), pid 7121 (tionapp.staging)
2023-08-03 15:10:00.481 11906-11906 DEBUG                   pid-11906                            A  Cmdline: com.sample.myapp.staging
2023-08-03 15:10:00.481 11906-11906 DEBUG                   pid-11906                            A  pid: 7121, tid: 10169, name: DefaultDispatch  >>> com.sample.myapp.staging <<<
2023-08-03 15:10:00.481 11906-11906 DEBUG                   pid-11906                            A        #22 pc 00000000001684e2  /data/app/~~EyOQK-IGM1Tjn1JUuoViFg==/com.sample.myapp.staging--XeqY505j54nitjwaSL3xA==/base.apk (okhttp3.RequestBody$Companion$asRequestBody$1.writeTo+62)
2023-08-03 15:10:00.481 11906-11906 DEBUG                   pid-11906                            A        #25 pc 0000000000162fe6  /data/app/~~EyOQK-IGM1Tjn1JUuoViFg==/com.sample.myapp.staging--XeqY505j54nitjwaSL3xA==/base.apk (okhttp3.MultipartBody.writeTo+30)
2023-08-03 15:10:00.481 11906-11906 DEBUG                   pid-11906                            A        #29 pc 000000000017a500  /data/app/~~EyOQK-IGM1Tjn1JUuoViFg==/com.sample.myapp.staging--XeqY505j54nitjwaSL3xA==/base.apk (okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept+100)
2023-08-03 15:10:00.482 11906-11906 DEBUG                   pid-11906                            A        #36 pc 0000000000186108  /data/app/~~EyOQK-IGM1Tjn1JUuoViFg==/com.sample.myapp.staging--XeqY505j54nitjwaSL3xA==/base.apk (okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept+164)
2023-08-03 15:10:00.482 11906-11906 DEBUG                   pid-11906                            A        #43 pc 000000000000c792  /data/app/~~EyOQK-IGM1Tjn1JUuoViFg==/com.sample.myapp.staging--XeqY505j54nitjwaSL3xA==/base.apk (com.sample.myapp.network.NetworkModule$TokenInterceptor.intercept+150)
2023-08-03 15:10:00.482 11906-11906 DEBUG                   pid-11906                            A        #46 pc 000000000000c5f2  /data/app/~~EyOQK-IGM1Tjn1JUuoViFg==/com.sample.myapp.staging--XeqY505j54nitjwaSL3xA==/base.apk (com.sample.myapp.network.NetworkModule$JsonResponseInterceptor.intercept+102)
2023-08-03 15:10:00.482 11906-11906 DEBUG                   pid-11906                            A        #50 pc 000000000017d866  /data/app/~~EyOQK-IGM1Tjn1JUuoViFg==/com.sample.myapp.staging--XeqY505j54nitjwaSL3xA==/base.apk (okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute+94)
2023-08-03 15:10:00.482 11906-11906 DEBUG                   pid-11906                            A        #52 pc 00000000002058be  /data/app/~~EyOQK-IGM1Tjn1JUuoViFg==/com.sample.myapp.staging--XeqY505j54nitjwaSL3xA==/base.apk (retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute+90)
2023-08-03 15:10:00.482 11906-11906 DEBUG                   pid-11906                            A        #54 pc 000000000020ea2c  /data/app/~~EyOQK-IGM1Tjn1JUuoViFg==/com.sample.myapp.staging--XeqY505j54nitjwaSL3xA==/base.apk (retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual+84)
2023-08-03 15:10:00.482 11906-11906 DEBUG                   pid-11906                            A        #56 pc 0000000000443a80  /data/app/~~EyOQK-IGM1Tjn1JUuoViFg==/com.sample.myapp.staging--XeqY505j54nitjwaSL3xA==/base.apk (io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe+64)
2023-08-03 15:10:00.482 11906-11906 DEBUG                   pid-11906                            A        #58 pc 000000000020e522  /data/app/~~EyOQK-IGM1Tjn1JUuoViFg==/com.sample.myapp.staging--XeqY505j54nitjwaSL3xA==/base.apk (retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual+22)
2023-08-03 15:10:00.482 11906-11906 DEBUG                   pid-11906                            A        #60 pc 0000000000443a80  /data/app/~~EyOQK-IGM1Tjn1JUuoViFg==/com.sample.myapp.staging--XeqY505j54nitjwaSL3xA==/base.apk (io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe+64)
2023-08-03 15:10:00.482 11906-11906 DEBUG                   pid-11906                            A        #62 pc 00000000004d77b2  /data/app/~~EyOQK-IGM1Tjn1JUuoViFg==/com.sample.myapp.staging--XeqY505j54nitjwaSL3xA==/base.apk (io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSingleSingle.subscribeActual+26)
2023-08-03 15:10:00.482 11906-11906 DEBUG                   pid-11906                            A        #64 pc 00000000004470ce  /data/app/~~EyOQK-IGM1Tjn1JUuoViFg==/com.sample.myapp.staging--XeqY505j54nitjwaSL3xA==/base.apk (io.reactivex.Single.subscribe+62)
2023-08-03 15:10:00.482 11906-11906 DEBUG                   pid-11906                            A        #66 pc 00000000004f2cd6  /data/app/~~EyOQK-IGM1Tjn1JUuoViFg==/com.sample.myapp.staging--XeqY505j54nitjwaSL3xA==/base.apk (io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleMap.subscribeActual+26)
2023-08-03 15:10:00.482 11906-11906 DEBUG                   pid-11906                            A        #68 pc 00000000004470ce  /data/app/~~EyOQK-IGM1Tjn1JUuoViFg==/com.sample.myapp.staging--XeqY505j54nitjwaSL3xA==/base.apk (io.reactivex.Single.subscribe+62)
2023-08-03 15:10:00.482 11906-11906 DEBUG                   pid-11906                            A        #70 pc 00000000004ef652  /data/app/~~EyOQK-IGM1Tjn1JUuoViFg==/com.sample.myapp.staging--XeqY505j54nitjwaSL3xA==/base.apk (io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleDoOnError.subscribeActual+22)
2023-08-03 15:10:00.482 11906-11906 DEBUG                   pid-11906                            A        #72 pc 00000000004470ce  /data/app/~~EyOQK-IGM1Tjn1JUuoViFg==/com.sample.myapp.staging--XeqY505j54nitjwaSL3xA==/base.apk (io.reactivex.Single.subscribe+62)
2023-08-03 15:10:00.482 11906-11906 DEBUG                   pid-11906                            A        #74 pc 00000000004f332a  /data/app/~~EyOQK-IGM1Tjn1JUuoViFg==/com.sample.myapp.staging--XeqY505j54nitjwaSL3xA==/base.apk (io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleOnErrorReturn.subscribeActual+22)
2023-08-03 15:10:00.482 11906-11906 DEBUG                   pid-11906                            A        #76 pc 00000000004470ce  /data/app/~~EyOQK-IGM1Tjn1JUuoViFg==/com.sample.myapp.staging--XeqY505j54nitjwaSL3xA==/base.apk (io.reactivex.Single.subscribe+62)
2023-08-03 15:10:00.482 11906-11906 DEBUG                   pid-11906                            A        #78 pc 0000000000446e7c  /data/app/~~EyOQK-IGM1Tjn1JUuoViFg==/com.sample.myapp.staging--XeqY505j54nitjwaSL3xA==/base.apk (io.reactivex.Single.subscribe+64)
2023-08-03 15:10:00.482 11906-11906 DEBUG                   pid-11906                            A        #79 pc 0000000002214a0c  /memfd:jit-cache (deleted) (com.sample.myapp.services.UploadVideoWorkManager.upload+2364)
2023-08-03 15:10:00.482 11906-11906 DEBUG                   pid-11906                            A        #81 pc 0000000000013bee  /data/app/~~EyOQK-IGM1Tjn1JUuoViFg==/com.sample.myapp.staging--XeqY505j54nitjwaSL3xA==/base.apk (com.sample.myapp.services.UploadVideoWorkManager.access$upload+22)
2023-08-03 15:10:00.482 11906-11906 DEBUG                   pid-11906                            A        #82 pc 0000000002149f8c  /memfd:jit-cache (deleted) (com.sample.myapp.services.UploadVideoWorkManager$upload$1.invoke+4332)
```

**Note** : I am using jackson to convert array to string and string to array back to save in DB. Tried commenting it out to check whether this is the issue, but still app crashed. As per profiler memory,CPU and Energy were not much too.